# Blocks in matrix

Tags: matrices

I am looking for something that looks like:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea as to how to implement this?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Squares in Matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161299/5764)

Comment: [may be it's wise to make an attempt to build MWE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161299/squares-in-matrix#comment369122_161299)

Answer (score 1):

Although closed, this approach is easier than the referrals, having its merits.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[papersize={10cm,5cm}]{geometry}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\temp}{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue}}}
\newcommand*{\tempred}{\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{red}}}
\[
B=\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccc}\cline{1-2}
\tempred &\tempred  &       &       &        &          &        \\ \cline{1-3}
\temp    &          &\temp  &       &        &          &        \\ \cline{1-4}
         & \temp    &       & \temp &        &          &        \\ \cline{2-5}
         &          & \temp &       & \temp  &          &        \\ \cline{3-6}
         &          &       & \temp &        & \temp    &        \\ \cline{4-7}
         &          &       &       &  \temp &          & \temp  \\ \cline{5-7}
         &          &       &       &        & \temp    &        \\ \cline{6-6}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
b_1\\
b_2\\
b_3\\
\cdot\\
\cdot\\
\cdot\\
b_7
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```