# Can I put \fbox along the diagonal so that they touch each other?

Tags: boxes, matrices

I am creating a block-diagonal matrix and want to use boxes along the diagonal but the boxes don't touch each other, so it looks funny.

What's a workaround for this?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}       
    \fbox{$B_1$} & 0 & 0  \\
     0 & \fbox{$B_2$} & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & \fbox{$B_3$} \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

something like the matrix in the middle ...of this answer (but without the red and color filling)

[Squares in Matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161299/squares-in-matrix/161368#161368)

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @cfr, nope, I will try that now.  But the other issue is:  the boxes don't touch each other, which I would like for a block-diagonal matrix....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The space between the columns is controlled by the dimen register `\arraycolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \fbox{$B_1$} & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & \fbox{$B_2$} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \fbox{$B_3$} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Without touching the delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \,\fbox{$B_1$} & 0 & 0\,  \\
    \,0 & \fbox{$B_2$} & 0\, \\
    \,0 & 0 & \fbox{$B_3$}\, \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The size of the delimiters are at least `\delimiterfactor` per mille of the formula height or the height of the formula minus `\delimitershortfall`. Full size is achieved by either

\delimiterfactor=1000\relax

or

```
\setlength{\delimitershortfall}{0pt}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  % \delimiterfactor=1000 %
  \setlength{\delimitershortfall}{0pt}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \,\fbox{$B_1$} & 0 & 0\,  \\
    \,0 & \fbox{$B_2$} & 0\, \\
    \,0 & 0 & \fbox{$B_3$}\, \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Colored boxes would also be possible as in Zarko's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330598/16967):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\delimitershortfall}{0pt}
  \newcommand*{\myfbox}[1]{%
    \fcolorbox{red}{red!20!white}{$#1$}%
  }
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \,\myfbox{B_1} & 0 & 0\,  \\
    \,0 & \myfbox{B_2} & 0\, \\
    \,0 & 0 & \myfbox{B_3}\, \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with colored boxes]

Comment: awesome, @Heiko.  How could I get the matrix brackets to be big enough to accommodate the boxes?

Comment: @user58865 See updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

[image]

Well, this matrix is drawn ...

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m1)    [matrix of nodes,
                 left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},
                 row sep=-0.5pt,column sep=-0.5pt,
                 every node/.style={inner sep=5pt}
                 ]
{
|[draw]| $B_1$ &   0           &   0             \\
 0            & |[draw]| $B_2$ &   0             \\
 0            &   0           & |[draw]| $B_3$   \\
 };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

by `tikz` with TikZ library `matrix`. Distance between cells of matrix as well to its brackets are set by `inner sep=5pt`. Cells with "frame" have option `|[draw]|`.

**Addendum:**
Since the matrix is now actually image, it is simple to present on more fancy ways. For example as:

[image]

MWE for above version of matrix is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m1)    [matrix of nodes,
                 left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},
                 row sep=-0.5pt,column sep=-0.5pt,
                 every node/.style={inner sep=5pt},
                 F/.style = {draw=red, line width=0.5pt, fill=red!20}
                 ]
{
|[F]| $B_1$ &   0           &   0           \\
 0          & |[F]| $B_2$   &   0           \\
 0          &   0           & |[F]| $B_3$   \\
 };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```